# How to merge string to JSON using c#

Tags: c#, json

hello i want to post to api but unfortunately there is problem to merge, insert or add the string into it.. please help

merge attempt 1: failed api cant read even 1.

```
[{"Key":"RatingName","Value":"testing from web"},{"Key":"RatingCode","Value":"1234"},{"Key":"RatingDesc","Value":"1234"},{"Key":"Levels","Value":"[{\"SortOrder\":\"1\",\"LvlName\":\"1\",\"LvlScore\":\"1\",\"LvlDesc\":\"1\"},{\"SortOrder\":\"12\",\"LvlName\":\"12\",\"LvlScore\":\"12\",\"LvlDesc\":\"12\"}]"}]
```

merge attempt 2 api can read the data but not Levels value: (i just insert string into KeyValuePair and put the Levels value as string) and using FormUrlEncodedContent before post to API

```
RatingName=testing+from+web&RatingCode=1234&RatingDesc=1234&Levels=%5B%7B%22SortOrder%22%3A%221%22%2C%22LvlName%22%3A%221%22%2C%22LvlScore%22%3A%221%22%2C%22LvlDesc%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%7B%22SortOrder%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22LvlName%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22LvlScore%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22LvlDesc%22%3A%2212%22%7D%5D
```

current JSON:

```
 {
 "RatingName":"testing from web",
 "RatingCode":"1234",
 "RatingDesc":"1234",
 "Levels": "" 
 }
```

how to insert into Levels with string: (below is literally string not array)

```
string =  [{"SortOrder":"1",
             "LvlName":"1",
             "LvlScore":"1",
             "LvlDesc":"1"},
           {"SortOrder":"12",
             "LvlName":"12",
             "LvlScore":"12",
             "LvlDesc":"12"}]
```

my expectation is :

```
{
     "RatingName":"testing from web",
     "RatingCode":"1234",
     "RatingDesc":"1234"
     "Levels": [{
                 "SortOrder":"1",
                 "LvlName":"1",
                 "LvlScore":"1",
                 "LvlDesc":"1"
                 },
                {
                 "SortOrder":"12",
                 "LvlName":"12",
                 "LvlScore":"12",
                 "LvlDesc":"12"
                 }] 
   }
```

Comment: can you use newtonsoft to convert string into json

Comment: "there is problem"...and what is the problem exactly? Please show us your attempt to perform this task and explain what's going wrong. This isn't a free write-my-code service, you're expected to demonstrate that you tried to solve it yourself first before asking for the free time of others to help you. Please edit your question to include the necessary extra information.

Comment: @JangliCoder that sting sould be like this :
[{\"SortOrder\":\"1\",\"LvlName\":\"1\",\"LvlScore\":\"1\",\"LvlDesc\":\"1\"},{\"SortOrder\":\"12\",\"LvlName\":\"12\",\"LvlScore\":\"12\",\"LvlDesc\":\"12\"}]

how to merge into Levels?

Comment: P.S. As you're new to Stackoverflow (welcome!) I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: As a general point, the logical thing to do here would be to deserialise both sets of JSON to a suitable class structure, modify the data within that structure as needed, and then serialise the combined data back into JSON. JSON is a format primarily for storage and transmission of data. It's not intended to be directly manipulated in the way you appear to be suggesting, and thus it's difficult to do so, as you've discovered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626849/how-to-append-a-json-file-without-disturbing-the-formatting describes a similar situation and provides a solution

Comment: So `Levels` in your API is expected to be an array of objects or a string? Because in your *before* it's a string (`""`) in your /after/ it's an array `[...]`

Comment: @derpirscher array of object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Newtonsoft.Json.
Here is an example of code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        JToken o1 = JToken.Parse("{\"RatingName\":\"testing from web\",\"RatingCode\":\"1234\",\"RatingDesc\":\"1234\",\"Levels\": \"\" }");
        JToken o2 = JToken.Parse("[{\"SortOrder\":\"1\", \"LvlName\":\"1\", \"LvlScore\":\"1\", \"LvlDesc\":\"1\"}, {\"SortOrder\":\"12\", \"LvlName\":\"12\", \"LvlScore\":\"12\", \"LvlDesc\":\"12\"}]");
        
        o1["Levels"] = o2;
        
        Console.WriteLine(o1.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: wow ! thats help me alot ! ok now how to post JToken to PostAsync(apiurl, o1);
should i change it to something?

Comment: you may convert JToken to string JSON: o1.ToString().