# c# File.WriteAllText overwriting new text on old Text

Tags: c#, json.net

While inserting new text into Json file its overwriting new text (insted of writing in new line).
Here is my code

```
public static void WriteToJson()
    {
        string filepath = @"../../SchemaList.json";
       // string filepath = @"C:\HoX_code\learning\Readjson\Readjson\SchemaList.json";

        List<SchemaInfo> _oscheme = new List<SchemaInfo>();
        _oscheme.Add(new SchemaInfo()
        {
            AuthenticateCmdlets= "AuthenticateCmdlets1",
            GetPowerState= "GetPowerState1",
            PowerOff= "PowerOff",
            PowerOn= "PowerOn",
        });
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_oscheme.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\HoX_code\learning\Readjson\Readjson\SchemaList.json"))
        {
             sw.Write(json);
        }
        ///  File.WriteAllText(@"../../SchemaList.json", json);
    }
```

Here i use **File.WriteAllText** &  **StreamWriter** Both are working same

Comment: That is how streams work. What is your actual question? What are your actual goals?

Comment: @JonasH When i run first Time its updating Text as [
  {
    "AuthenticateCmdlets": "AuthenticateCmdlets1",
    "GetPowerState": "GetPowerState1",
    "PowerOff": "PowerOff",
    "PowerOn": "PowerOn"
  }
]   If i update anyThing & Run again its overwrite old text as new Text E.G  PowerOff To POWEROFF

Comment: Again you are are just describing how it works, not what you are asking about or what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @MDGosoddin you should not create a list and then create an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behaivour. Checking the [documentation for `File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-6.0) it says

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. **If the target file already exists, it is overwritten**.

(Emphasis mine)

You're going to want to use [`File.AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-6.0), it's documentation states

> Appends the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does not already exist.

If you want to use streams, then the `StreamWriter` constructor has a parameter to specify whether or not to append or overwrite text in a file [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)) (Credits go to @vernou, I totally forgot this constructor existed)

But do note that this will result in invalid JSON, as JSON may only have 1 base object and this will result in multiple. If you actually want to append to the serialized JSON object, the I recommend you check out [How to Append a json file without disturbing the formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20626849/9363973)

Comment: Yes ur right  File.AppendAllText write as [
  {
    "AuthenticateCmdlets": "AuthenticateCmdlets1",
    "GetPowerState": "GetPowerState1",
    "PowerOff": "PowerOff",
    "PowerOn": "PowerOn"
  }
][
  {
    "AuthenticateCmdlets": "AuthenticateCmdlets1",
    "GetPowerState": "GetPowerState1",
    "PowerOff": "PowerOff",
    "PowerOn": "PowerOn"
  }
]